# Incremental Loading c# Metro App

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I need incremental loading in my store app, for large data. i see sample on mdsn, and read another answers. How i can incremental loading data, if my data is three `ObservableCollection<T>` and all them need to binding in GridView?(Sorry for my English)
sample what i mean:

```
private async Task<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadDataAsync(uint count)
{                                       
    XDocument document = await ParseUrl("");
    var xmlreader = document.CreateReader();
    feed results = GetFeed(xmlreader);
    newsFeed = results; 
    return new LoadMoreItemsResult {Count = count};
}

public class feed 
{

    public ObservableCollection<> Posts { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<> Profiles { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<> Groups { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the most appropriate example

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-8-metro-Improve-GridView-and-ListView-with-SemanticZoom-and-Incremental-Loading.aspx

Have a look at it.. it supports Incremental loading as you are trying to use it.

Comment: Look,If i understand you correctly,then its all i do. Problem in incremental loading, method LoadMoreItemsAsync() newer called

Comment: And in GridView i used DataContext="{Binding Feed}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Posts}"

Comment: Yeap something like that as long as you bind it correctly, population of collection can then be done independently

Comment: what about problem? How i can get LoadMoreItemsAsync() for Posts or used this method for Feed?

Comment: If you use the mechanism I am talking about, the return type will just be Task (ie it returns nothing. it populates your collection and ends)

Comment: i don't understand how this run LoadMoreItemsAsync,can you give me an example?

Comment: thanks for help=) but i don't think this helps, or don't understand you). Look, class Feed: ISupportIncrementalLoading, and his contains HasMoreItems and LoadMoreItemsAsync, but this methods newer called by system, and its I need)

Comment: in last example,"InfiniteSequence : ObservableCollection<int>, ISupportIncrementalLoading" but I need Feed:ISupportIncrementalLoading

Comment: You need to be able to extend examples

Comment: This example demonstratees us how to use ISupportIncrementallLoading for ObservableCollection. As a result I have made it successfully for Posts, but because of Posts are used with 2 collections of Groups and Profiles I need to realize incremental loading for Feed class. Is It possible?)

Comment: I don't think its impossible. you just need to look at the sample and then work out the flow for your app.